# Transfer from English page to Arabic page

Tags: translation

I have a button at the top of the website in  **header.php**. That button should transfer me to the Arabic version of the page if I am on an English page.

For example, on **contact.html** the button should transfer me to **contact-ar.html** and on **info.html** the button should transfer me to **info-ar.html**.

```
<li><a href="#">arabic</a></li>
```

I want to know if there is any way to edit part of the **header.php** from outside?

Comment: Your question is tagged as `wordpress.com` which is off-topic on this site. Is it the mistake?

Comment: no i am creating my website by using wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. This is given that the original page url has a `.html` in it (`contact.html` and `info.html`)

```
<li><a href="<?php
if (false !== strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '.html')) {
    $uri = str_replace('.html', '-ar.html', strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
} else {
    $uri = '';
}
echo home_url($uri);
?>">arabic</a></li>
```

Comment: i didn't understand and i think you miss understood me i want for example contact-eng.html includes a button that is added in the header part by the header.php when i click this button it goes to page contact-ar.html

Comment: @sarah you mean you want that link to be automatically added to `header.php` file without you editing that file?

Comment: yes i don't want to edit the file i want to make for each page a link that tansfer to arabic page

Comment: @sarah That might not be an easy task to accomplish, the important question is where do you want that link to appear? Do you want to append it to a WP navigation menu? Or it is part of WP categories or pages list? Please edit your question posting some more details.

Comment: i edited the question but couldn't attach image

Comment: Would this link change to english if you are already on an arab page?

Answer (score 0):

The button might not be the best route to solve this problem. If your aim is to have a separate page for each language then look into using the WordPress ML plugin. This will give you the tools (and buttons) to properly have your site be in two languages.